# When is std::move redundant?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

Simply put I have this class in which I'd like to move the wrapped object.

```
std::string m_S;
string_t(string_t&& s)
  : m_S(s.m_S)
{
}
```

*I omitted the surrounding class structure, just added the member `m_S` for completeness sake.*

Am I required to wrap the member access with a `std::move` or will this just work since `s` is passed as a rvalue reference?

Comment: You need `std::move` here, because `s` is an lvalue here. There are good duplicates around, I will try to find one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do need `move` here. `s.m_S` is an *lvalue* expression, so will not bind to an `_rvalue_` reference.

Even `s` itself is an *lvalue* expression, so you'd also need `move` if you wanted to use that to move-construct a variable.

Comment: When you think about what `std::move` really does and what constitutes a rvalue (temporary) I think I'm starting to get it though there are instances when this is done for you which isn't entirely self explanatory (such as return by value).

Answer (score 1):

If the function-arguments type is rvalue-reference, the argument is still an lvalue inside the function (as well as for ctors init-list).

Thus, you really need to use `std::move` or equivalent if you mean it.